# Redux dispatches are not firing for fetching API

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi I'm new at using redux and I can't really figure out why the FetchUsers() doesn't work in dispatching and the users I fetch in App.js is always an empty array.Should I use useDispatch()? or  is it adding a another middleware?

**reducer**

```
    import {
  FETCH_USERS,
  FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_USERS_FAILURE,
} from "../actions/types";

const initialValues = {
  loading: false,
  users: [],
  error: "",
};
const usersreducer = (state = initialValues, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USERS:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, users: action.payload };
    case FETCH_USERS_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**actions:**

```
  import { FETCH_USERS, FETCH_USERS_FAILURE, FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS } from "./types";

const fetchUsersRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERS,
  };
};
const fetchUsersFailure = (error) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERS_FAILURE,
    payload: error,
  };
};
    const fetchUsersSuccess = (users) => {
      return {
        type: FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
        payload: users,
      };
    };

export const FetchUsers = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchUsersRequest());
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => {
        const users = res.data;
        dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(users));
      })
      .then((err) => {
        const error = "error";
        dispatch(fetchUsersFailure(error));
      });
  };
};
```

**index:**

```
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./reducers";
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js:

```
 import { FetchUsers } from "./actions/actions";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const App = () => {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  useEffect(() => {
    FetchUsers();
    console.log(users.users);
  }, []);
```

........................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

Simply calling a thunk will not cause anything to happen; it will just return another function and do nothing. You need to dispatch it the same way you would dispatch normal actions. Dispatching the thunk will actually run it, and will also allow it to access your store so that you can dispatch other actions and access the current state of your store if you want to. `FetchUsers()` really is just a regular function; by itself, it doesn't have any way to access your store. Dispatching it provides it with that access.

```js
import { FetchUsers } from "./actions/actions";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const App = () => {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(FetchUsers());
    console.log(users.users);
  }, []);
```

See the [redux-thunk docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) for more information and examples.

Comment: I've already done that sir but it still return an empty array.

Comment: If `users.users` is an empty array after you dispatch `FetchUsers()`, then that's a completely unrelated problem. `users.users` is the old state from before you dispatched the thunk. If the thunk updates that data in the store, then your component will re-render with that new data.